# Why does horizontal padding affect vertical overflow?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-for-android

> **Update:** it seems to be a bug, as it happens **only in Chrome** for Android and Chrome DevTools device mode. [See and star the bug report.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595457#)

The code below causes vertical overflow on mobile devices, as long as the horizontal padding is greater than 50%. [Online demo.](http://bolvari.hu/public/so36040958.html) Why does this happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style>

    div
    {
        background:red;
        height:200px;
        padding:0 55%;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you voted for closing this? Should I clarify the question? I've already checked all the similar questions, none of them helps.

Comment: Test #1 - 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit) Chrome DevTools on Win 10 Pro: CONFIRMED.

Comment: Test #2 - Chrome 49.0.2623.91 on Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1: CONFIRMED.

Comment: Test #3 - Android Browser on Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1: disconfirmed.

Comment: Test #4 - Firefox 45.0 on Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1: disconfirmed.

Comment: Test #5 - Opera Mini 15.0.2125.101257 on Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1: disconfirmed.

Comment: Test #6 - Opera 35.0.2070.100283 on Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1: disconfirmed.

Comment: Test #7 - Safari (no version info) on iPhone 4(S?) running iOS (no version info): disconfirmed.